# Does the Xively API -> Product Management -> Devices -> Update a Device work for anyone?

Tags: xively

As you know, Cosm just turned into Xively on Tuesday.

They've added APIs for Products and Devices, and I'm trying to connect to them.

I'm running into problems getting the "Update a Device" API to work. The specific API is documented here: 
https://xively.com/dev/docs/api/product_management/devices/update_device/

Anyone else have problems getting this call to return anything other than a 500 error message: '{"title":"Oops, something's broken","errors":"We've been unable to complete your request due to a problem with our server"}' ?

Answer (score 1):

it's probably best mailing support@xively.com with this question I think. I just tried making the serial number update request on one of my devices via the API, and it seemed to work ok; so if you mail them then they'll be able to investigate your specific device.